# Recursive Maze Solver Issue

Tags: java, maze

I'm making a recursive Java maze program and I'm stuck on the part when it comes to calling to my subroutines `goNorth()`, `goWest()`, `goEast()` and `goSouth()`. Basically my problem involves the fact that it calls to one subroutine, but within that subroutine it doesn't pick up on my other else if and else statements therefore not making it pick up on the other possibilities. Please assist, I appreciate your upcoming answer.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class RecursiveMazeSolverv2 {

  static Scanner in;
  static int row = 0;
  static int col = 0;
  static char maze[][];
  static int rowSize = 0;
  static int colSize = 0;
  static boolean success = true;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    while (true) {
      try {
        in = new Scanner(new File("Maze1.txt")); 
        break;
      }
      catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Wrong File"); 
      }
    }
    rowSize = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
    colSize = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());

    maze = new char[rowSize][colSize];

    String lineOfInput = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < maze.length; i++) {
      lineOfInput = in.nextLine();
      for (int j = 0; j < maze.length; j++) {
        maze[i][j] = lineOfInput.charAt(j);
      }
    }

    displayGrid();

    for (int i = 0; i < maze.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < maze.length; j++) {
        if (maze[i][j] == 'S') {
          maze[i][j]='+';
          System.out.println("Starting coordinates: " + i + ", " + j);
          row = i;
          col = j;
        }
      }
    }

if (goNorth(row, col))
  displayGrid();
else
  System.out.println("Impossible!");
  }


  static Boolean goNorth(int row, int col) {
    if (maze[row][col] == '.') {
      maze[row][col] = '+';
      return goNorth(row -1, col);
    }

    else if (maze[row][col] == 'G') {
      return true;
    }

    else {
      success = goNorth(row, col);
      if (success == false) {
        success = goWest(row, col -1); 
      }
      if (success == false) {
        success = goEast(row, col +1); 
      }
      if (success == false) {
        success = goSouth(row +1, col); 
      }
      if (success == false) {
        maze[row][col] = '.';
        success = false; }
      return false; 
    }

  }
   static Boolean goWest(int row, int col) {
    if (maze[row][col] == '.') {
      maze[row][col] = '+';
      return goWest(row, col -1);
    }

    else if (maze[row][col] == 'G') {
      return true;
    }

    else {
     success = goWest(row, col);
      if (success == false) {
        success = goNorth(row -1, col); 
      }
      if (success == false) {
        success = goSouth(row +1, col); 
      }
       if (success == false) {
        success = goEast(row, col -1); 
       }
      if (success == false) {
        maze[row][col] = '.';
        success = false; }
      return false; 
    }

  }

   static Boolean goEast(int row, int col) {
    if (maze[row][col] == '.') {
      maze[row][col] = '+';
      return goEast(row, col +1);
    }

    else if (maze[row][col] == 'G') {
      return true;
    }

    else {
     success = goEast(row, col);
      if (success == false) {
        success = goNorth(row -1, col); 
      }
      if (success == false) {
        success = goSouth(row +1, col); 
      }
       if (success == false) {
        success = goWest(row, col -1); 
       }
      if (success == false) {
        maze[row][col] = '.';
        success = false; }
      return false; 
    }

  }


   static Boolean goSouth(int row, int col) {
    if (maze[row][col] == '.') {
      maze[row][col] = '+';
      return goSouth(row +1, col);
    }

    else if (maze[row][col] == 'G') {
      return true;
    }

    else {
     success = goSouth(row, col);
      if (success == false) {
        success = goNorth(row -1, col); 
      }
      if (success == false) {
        success = goWest(row, col -1); 
      }
       if (success == false) {
        success = goEast(row, col +1); 
       }
      if (success == false) {
        maze[row][col] = '.';
        success = false; }
      return false; 
    }

  }

  public static void displayGrid() {
    for (int j = 0; j < maze.length; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < maze.length; k++) {
        System.out.print(maze[j][k] + " "); 
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Sorry, I can't post the actual maze in here, it wont display right.

Comment: "but within that subroutine it doesn't pick up on my other else if and else statements therefore not making it pick up on the other possibilities. " Please rephrase: I cannot understand what you mean.

Comment: Learn how objects work and what the 'static' keyword does first. Everything should not be static. Here's a decent tutorial on objects.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm

Comment: okay so it picks up on the periods and will replace it with '+'. But it won't backtrack it all to changing it back to .'s if it's not on the right path & it doesn't call to the other subroutines if success=false.

Comment: Why have you bothered writing this program in Java?  Your whole program is written procedurally without any discernable attempts to use any object-oriented approaches or to modularize your problem.  I would say that you clearly do not "get" object orientation.

Comment: it's an assignment for school, I have no choice.

Comment: Did the assignment state that you should do it in a procedural way without OO?

Answer (score 0):

Problems I see:

1. As others eluded to, you shouldn't make everything `static`.  Without going into a super long and boring discussion, making everything `static` means that the values you set in your recursive calls will modify the value for all calls.  You are effectively over-writing each recursive call with values you are setting in subsequent recursive calls.  You will want to make most of those method-scoped variables so that the value will only be valid in the scope of that method call.
2. Your recursive calls are not in the same order.  You need to do the same calls in the same step each time: Try North, then South, then East, then West.  Whatever order you pick, the calls need to be in the same order.  In fact, I am not really sure why you decided to have separate methods for each direction...why not have one method called "move" that tries to go North, then recurses, then tries to go South, then recurses, then tries to go East and recurses, then West and recurses.  The way you have things coded, there is no telling where the code will go in the maze, and most likely you will end up going around in circles.
3. This isn't directly linked to why it's not working, but you REALLY need to work on your code formatting, in particular your tabbing.  Your code looks like it's all over the place.  I can only imagine that that is making it WAY harder to troubleshoot that it needs to be.

**Edit - Example**

I will try to do this in a way to guide you without giving you a copy/paste answer, so this will be pseudo-code'ish.

```
/**
 * My move recursion
 */
public boolean move(int currRow, int currCol) {
  // See if we solved it...
  if (solved) {
    return true;
  }

  // Try to go north first...
  if (maze[currRow-1][currCol] == '.') {
    if (move(int currRow-1, currCol)) {
      // Mark this with the "good" path and return true
    }
  }

  // Try to go east next...
  if (maze[currRow][currCol+1] == '.') {
    if (move(int currRow, currCol+1)) {
      // Mark this with the "good" path and return true
    }
  }

  // Try to go south next...
  if (maze[currRow+1][currCol] == '.') {
    if (move(int currRow+1, currCol)) {
      // Mark this with the "good" path and return true
    }
  }

  // Try to go west...
  if (maze[currRow][currCol-1] == '.') {
    if (move(int currRow, currCol-1)) {
      // Mark this with the "good" path and return true
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

So, basically we check if we are "solved".  If not, see if we can go north.  If we can, see if the next call is solved.  Repeat for east, south, and west.  Eventually one of the recursive calls will get to the solved condition, which will trigger each of the recursive calls to pass the inner if, which marks the maze and returns true, thus creating a chain reaction that ends up popping back up the call stack until you are done with the recursion.

Things to note with recursion:

1. It typically needs to be a process that can be broken into one or more repeatable, autonomous steps.  This doesn't mean it has to be one method, but if it's multiple methods you HAVE to perform things within the method in the same order.  Otherwise, your logic get's out of sync.
2. It typically works best when you can break the "steps" into their smallest, most menial parts.  Overly complex recursive methods makes for hard debugging and lots and lots of crazy branching and looping.
3. You have to have a VERY clear "end", else you will recurse until you blow the stack up.
4. There should be a very clear distinction between variables/data/information that are "method level" and things that are "global".  In your case, the maze is global, the success and current position are not.

Comment: Thanks for your response :) But I don't really understand how to make it one method. I've just recently started recursion, so how would you recommend I get started with that one method?